# Add keywords at the bottom of a document

Tags: footnotes, sourcecode

I want to use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` in the place of `\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}`. However I want to add the following in the bottom of the first page

[image]

This is my codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\footnte{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification. Primary ..; Secondary ...}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using a package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing

% -------------
\makeatletter
\def\keywords{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Hello world.%
    \keywords{2010 \emph{Mathematics Subject Classification.} Primary ..; Secondary \dots}%
    \keywords{\emph{Key words and phrases.} Positive Operator \dots}%
    \footnote{Normal footnote}
    Some text here.
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 2):

With the `titlefoot` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing

 \usepackage{titlefoot}

\begin{document}

\unmarkedfntext{2010 Mathematics Subject Classification. Primary ..; Secondary ...\newline\hspace*{2em}Keywords:}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but what about key words and phrases?

Comment: @Schüler Just added

Comment: @Schüler Was my pleasure to help!